# Is there anything similar between low and high born?

Tags: word-request

Normally you say that someone with an average income is part of the middle class. 
If I look about the past...specifically the middle ages and even earlier I often find the terms "low born" and "high born" (or peasants and nobles).

I'm wondering though if there is any similar word in english that can be used for something in between low born and high born (thus something like the middle class. aka one word and then "born" after it)?

Nowadays I don't hear low born or high born too much only in combination with past times, but if there is something in the modern world I would also be interested in that.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand medieval society (non-expert), the rule was rather simple: noble or not noble (as in "having a title of nobility", unrelated to the inner qualities of ethics, morality...).

So "high born" was used for nobles, and "low born" for whoever was not noble.

What we call "middle class" today did not really exist in those times, even if some non-nobles were quite rich (e.g. some merchants). So it is very difficult (impossible?) to use a medieval term for something which did not exist at that time.